# How can I get part of regex match as a variable in python?

Tags: python, regex, perl

In Perl it is possible to do something like this (I hope the syntax is right...):

```
$string =~ m/lalala(I want this part)lalala/;
$whatIWant = $1;
```

I want to do the same in Python and get the text inside the parenthesis in a string like $1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See: [Python regex match objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile("lalala(I want this part)lalala")
>>> p.match("lalalaI want this partlalala").group(1)
'I want this part'
```

Answer (score 46):

If you want to get parts by name you can also do this:

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(?P<first_name>\w+) (?P<last_name>\w+)", "Malcom Reynolds")
>>> m.groupdict()
{'first_name': 'Malcom', 'last_name': 'Reynolds'}
```

The example was taken from the [re docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groupdict)

Comment: or take just what you need with `m.group("last_name")`

Answer (score 19):

```
import re
astr = 'lalalabeeplalala'
match = re.search('lalala(.*)lalala', astr)
whatIWant = match.group(1) if match else None
print(whatIWant)
```

A small note: in Perl, when you write

```
$string =~ m/lalala(.*)lalala/;
```

the regexp can match anywhere in the string. The equivalent is accomplished with the `re.search()` function, not the `re.match()` function,  which requires that the pattern match starting at the beginning of the string.

Comment: from python3.8 you can use the [walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) (`:=`): `if m := re.search(...): # access m.group(...)`

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
data = "some input data"
m = re.search("some (input) data", data)
if m: # "if match was successful" / "if matched"
  print m.group(1)
```

Check the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) for more.

Answer (score 1):

there's no need for regex. think simple.

```
>>> "lalala(I want this part)lalala".split("lalala")
['', '(I want this part)', '']
>>> "lalala(I want this part)lalala".split("lalala")[1]
'(I want this part)'
>>>
```

Comment: Very smart idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
match = re.match('lalala(I want this part)lalala', 'lalalaI want this partlalala')
print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

string_to_check = "other_text...lalalaI want this partlalala...other_text"

p = re.compile("lalala(I want this part)lalala")    # regex pattern
m = p.search(string_to_check)                       # use p.match if what you want is always at beginning of string

if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

In trying to convert a Perl program to Python that parses function names out of modules, I ran into this problem, I received an error saying "group" was undefined. I soon realized that the exception was being thrown because p.**match** / p.**search** returns 0 if there is not a matching string.

Thus, the group operator cannot function on it. So, to avoid an exception, check if a match has been stored and then apply the group operator.

```
import re

filename = './file_to_parse.py'

p = re.compile('def (\w*)')            # \w* greedily matches [a-zA-Z0-9_] character set


for each_line in open(filename,'r'):
    m = p.match(each_line)             # tries to match regex rule in p
    if m:
        m = m.group(1)
        print m
```