# What's the pythonic way to parse such a URI 'foo://user:pass@host:port' into proper variables?

Tags: python

Only the `host` part is not optional, that is to say the URI may has the following forms:

```
 1. foo://user:pass@host:port
 2. foo://host:port
 3. user@host
 4. host
```

and so on. If we have five variables to save the values of parts in such an URI, Is there a pythonic way to assign these values to the proper variables when they exist in the URI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (python 2) / [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module.

The [`urlparse()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) can handle all forms you mention, but note that without a scheme, the `user@host` and `host` portions are seen as a *path*:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('foo://user:pass@host:port')
ParseResult(scheme='foo', netloc='user:pass@host:port', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('foo://host:port')
ParseResult(scheme='foo', netloc='host:port', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('user@host')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='user@host', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urlparse('host')
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='host', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

That's easily worked around:

```
host = result.hostname or result.path.rpartition('@')[-1]
```

Comment: The only problem I see with this is when the protocol is not specified (it returns wrong values).

Comment: @JuanLopes: because it is indistinguishable from a file path.

Comment: I know, but OP specified that only the host is not optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `urlparse` module for doing this.

I think it is worth nothing though that you could also setup a series of regular expressions to grab and assign the wanted data to variables. This might come in handy if you want to do something similar, but not necessarily with a URI.

Here is another thread with a good example:
[How can I get part of regex match as a variable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800817/how-can-i-get-part-of-regex-match-as-a-variable-in-python)